# NSMutableData object not recognizing selectors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm currently trying to write an iPhone companion to a website that I'm developing. I'm trying to get JSON data from my website by making a controller a delegate of the NSURLConnection. Here's the problem though, I have an NSMutableData object named responseData initialized like so:

```
responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];
```

And I want to append data as it comes:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

However, this causes my app to crash and says in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFArray appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x6d0a640'
```

I'm pretty confident that appendData should be recognized, so I'm at a loss as to what the problem is here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to retain the object:

```
responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];

[responseData retain];
```

But that's not the common way of doing this. Simply use alloc/init:

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

But don't forget to release in dealloc:

```
[responseData release];
```

Comment: The first one worked for me as I was stuck with same problem. Strangely, I was already doing the second one but for some reason it was not working for me. It would be very helpful for me to know why it is not working for me. More strange thing is, the second one is working in another part of my code. Can you please throw some light on this situation?